# Is it "I read one of your comment" or "I read one of your comments"?

Tags: grammatical-number

Which one is correct? The first one implies that I read one specific comment but the second one that I read one comment out of many the person made?

Thanks!

Comment: It's “*I read one of your comments*”. Your latter explanation is correct. The first one is grammatically wrong.

Comment: Thank you both. The link was very helpful :)